# Code comments in template file show on page

Tags: 7, theming

Im using page--front.tpl.php to override my front page. Ive commented out the content with the code below, however this '-->' is shown on the page.

```
<!-- <?php print render($page['content']); ?> -->
```

How can I stop this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php #print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Comment: Is there no way of commenting out large blocks of code? EG one that contained a mix of html and php. Thanks

Comment: not really -- you can use C style comments (ex. /* .. */) to block out large chunks of code or html but the minute it hits a start or end <?php tag in your code its going to return to output